# How to load an editable table with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, html-table, datatables

My site uses AJAX to load menus without having to refresh the page. For future reference, the main php file that contains all the menus is the index.php file. One of these menus has an editable table, which uses AJAX, jQuery and Datatable plugin. All the menus seem to load correctly, but the table doesn't load upon the first click, and then after it does load, it acts wrong; I try to add a single record, but it adds a random number of the record instead (for example, like 16 records). Also, for some reason, the appearance of the table changes; it's normal if the script source (the script being the Datatable script) is a cdn link, however it's messed up a bit if the source is a file (even though the file has the same code, except for the names of buttons and etc shown being in Hungarian, instead of English). None of the listed problems happen if the table's menu is loaded normally, without AJAX, but loading it with AJAX just messes it up, and I have no clue why.

[Table after the first click on the Autok button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLXzF.png)

[This is how the table looks by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUcBH.png)

[Table after adding only one record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJsqz.png)

As you can see, even though I added just one record (the one with test1), it got inserted 6 times... also, everything on the site just doubled; double search bars, buttons, etc... before I added the test1 record, there really were only 9 entries, so it appears, the 9 entries text remained from before the record was added, and above that the new, 15 entries text was loaded. So, my question is: how do I make it, so that only that one records I actually inserted gets inserted (and not with a random number of copies)? Also, how do I get rid of the double search bars and such after insertion, and how do I make it, so that the table properly displays even after the first click on the Autok button on the left?

I tried using a newer jQuery and Database sourcecode, but it didn't do anything. I also tried to remove the $(document).ready(function()... parts of the code, either only from the index.php file, or from the autok.php file, but neither worked. As I mentioned before, if the table's menu is loaded without AJAX, everything works like a charm (the table itself still operates with AJAX), but I need it to load with AJAX, so I want to fix this. As for the database (MySQL), everything refreshes and works as it should, though for some reason I can't seem to delete the records that were wrongly inserted multiple times, because even if I click on delete (within phpmyadmin, it just... stays there.

This makes the table's menu (autok, which gets its content from autok.php) load without refreshing any pages, by clicking on its button (button's ID is autok), and then loading the table in a large div (which has the cell-content ID).

This is the code responsible for loading the Autok menu, it's found in my index.php file (just ignore the "belépés" and "regisztráció" parts, those work differently, not with AJAX):

```
    <div id="menuk" class='belso bal'>
             <?php
            if(empty($_SESSION["username"]))
            {
             echo"<a href='?p=belep' >Belépés</a>";      
            } 
            else
            {
              echo"<a href='autok.php' id='autok'>Autók</a>";
              echo"<a href='alkalmazottak.php' id='alkalmazottak'>Alkalmazottak</a>";
              echo"<a href='vevok.php' id='vevok'  >Vevők</a>";
            }
            echo"<a href='?p=reg'>Regisztráció</a>";
             ?> 
          </div>




          <div id="cell-content" class='belso jobb' >
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#autok").click(function(){
    $("#cell-content").load('autok.php');
  return false;
  });
  });

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#alkalmazottak").click(function(){
    $("#cell-content").load('alkalmazottak.php');
  return false;
  });
 });


  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#vevok").click(function(){
    $("#cell-content").load('vevok.php');
  return false;
  });
  });

</script>
```

This is the Autok menu's php (autok.php):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Autószalon</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <style>
#user_data {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#user_data td, #user_data th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#user_data tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#user_data tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

#user_data th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
</style>

 </head>
 <body>
   <h1 align="center">Autószalon</h1>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <br />
    <div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info">Hozzáad</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
    <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Autó</th>
       <th>Ár</th>
       <th>Alkalmazott</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){

  fetch_data();

  function fetch_data()
  {
   var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "ajax" : {
     url:"fetch.php",
     type:"POST"
    }
   });
  }

  function update_data(id, column_name, value)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"update.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{id:id, column_name:column_name, value:value},
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
     $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
     fetch_data();
    }
   });
   setInterval(function(){
    $('#alert_message').html('');
   }, 5000);
  }

  $(document).on('blur', '.update', function(){
   var id = $(this).data("id");
   var column_name = $(this).data("column");
   var value = $(this).text();
   update_data(id, column_name, value);
  });

  $('#add').click(function(){
   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>'
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Beszúrás</button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){
   var auto = $('#data1').text();
   var ar = $('#data2').text();
   var alkalmazott = $('#data3').text();
   if(auto != '' && ar != '' && alkalmazott !='')
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"insert.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{auto:auto, ar:ar, alkalmazott:alkalmazott},
     success:function(data)
     {
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Egy mezot kihagyott!");
   }
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   if(confirm("Biztosan torolni szeretne?"))
   {
    $.ajax({
     url:"delete.php",
     method:"POST",
     data:{id:id},
     success:function(data){
      $('#alert_message').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
      $('#user_data').DataTable().destroy();
      fetch_data();
     }
    });
    setInterval(function(){
     $('#alert_message').html('');
    }, 5000);
   }
  });
 });
</script>
```

As for the referenced PHPs, here is my fetch.php code:

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "autoszalon");
if (!mysqli_connect_errno() && mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8")) 
{

    $columns = array('ID', 'Auto', 'Ar', 'Alkalmazott');
$query = "SELECT * FROM automenu ";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
 $query .= '
 WHERE auto LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 OR alkalmazott LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
 ';
}

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$columns[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' 
 ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect, $query));

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query . $query1);

$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="Auto">' . $row["Auto"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="Ar">' . $row["Ar"] . '</div>';
  $sub_array[] = '<div contenteditable class="update" data-id="'.$row["id"].'" data-column="Alkalmazott">' . $row["Alkalmazott"] . '</div>';
 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Törlés</button>';
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function get_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM automenu";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 return mysqli_num_rows($result);
}

$output = array(
 "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 "recordsTotal"  =>  get_all_data($connect),
 "recordsFiltered" => $number_filter_row,
 "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
}


?>
```

Here is the update.php:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "autoszalon");
if (!mysqli_connect_errno() && mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8")) 
{

if(isset($_POST["id"]))
    {
 $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["value"]);
 $query = "UPDATE automenu SET ".$_POST["column_name"]."='".$value."' WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
        {
  echo 'Adat Frissitve';
        }
    }
}



?>
```

Here is the insert.php:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "autoszalon");
if (!mysqli_connect_errno() && mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8")) 
{
if(isset($_POST["auto"], $_POST["ar"], $_POST["alkalmazott"]))
{
 $auto = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["auto"]);
 $ar = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["ar"]);
 $alkalmazott = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["alkalmazott"]);
 $query = "INSERT INTO automenu(auto, ar, alkalmazott) VALUES('$auto', '$ar', '$alkalmazott')";
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
 {
  echo 'Adat Elmentve';
 }
}
}





?>
```

And here is the delete.php code:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "autoszalon");
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
 $query = "DELETE FROM automenu WHERE id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
 if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
 {
  echo 'Adat Torolve';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried to read your question, but there's too much text and too little code. The real problem is that I have no idea what this "menu table" really looks like.

Comment: Exactly what @KIKOSoftware said. Your description of the problem is so wordy and you never ask an actual question. Can you fix that?

Comment: I edited the question to make it far more transparent, hopefully. This is my first time asking a question here, so I apologise for any slip ups. :D